# Restful API authorizations mechanism

Tags: api, rest, authentication, authorization

I am building an RESTful API, below are some of its specifications:

1. Framework: Codeigniter, SaaS based application.
2. API using API-KEY to define the client [backbone application (web), android application, ios application]
3. API using Access-token to define the user who make the request through the client, and every access-token is related to dedicated user.
4. API authenticate the request by the API-KEY
5. API authorize the request through the access-token by defining scopes to which action each access-token was authorized to make.
6. API defines "Roles groups" where is every group have a lot of different permissions every user in the group should granted.

Currently I'm stack in the stage where I have to authorize the request so I could accept it or refuse and return "403 Unauthorized access", so here is the question:

What is the proper mechanism used to authorized the requests and achieving the following:

1. Checking the permissions defined earlier in "Roles group" for the user who made the request so I could authorized the request or refusing it.
2. some users may be able to change their profile settings except the password, how to authorize for such a request.

**working out:**
I am chooses to define scopes in every access-token, so whenever I received a request I will have eye on the scopes related to this access-token then comparing with scopes for the requested function in the controller `"hard coded in the controller, like below"` to check if he authorized or not, BUT something is always going wrong, & I never end with a result ... think that there is something I miss or the whole idea is wrong.

```
protected $methods = array(
    'authentication_post' => array('level' => 1, 'limit' => 1, 'avoid_token' => true, 'scope' => 'system:login'),
    'test_get' => array('level' => 1, 'limit' => 1, 'avoid_token' => true, 'scope' => 'user:enabled'),
    'authentication_get' => array('level' => 1, 'limit' => 1, 'avoid_token' => false, 'scope' => 'user:enabled something something something'),
);
```

P.S
I would like to understand, so kindly instead of saying that the solution in oauth, tell me how should it work :) :)

Comment: I'm not going to say that OAuth is your solution; however, you've just described OAuth 2, and in particular, scopes. OAuth is just a specification, but that being said, it's a pretty well written one that has a lot of eyeballs and hands on it. So, my advice is to read the OAuth 2 spec, because it's actually quite easy to read/understand (compared to other specifications). If you have specific projects/libraries that you're using (beyond the Codeigniter framework), please share those details.

Comment: @mansilladev Do you have any practice for how to handling the ACL lists